# How does the new File Plugin work on Cordova 3.4.0?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

According to the [plugin documentation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/blob/r1.0.1/doc/index.md) the app can access to different roots like files, files-external, documents, sdcard, cache, cache-external, and root.

How can the app access the cache's root, or another one, to store/get a file from there?

Comment: Do you wanna know how the plugin works(like an explanation of their code) or do you wanna know how to achieve read write using the plugin?

Comment: I know how the plugin works, but i can't find how to read or write in other roots. I only can see files root, i don't know how to change from files root to a cache root, for example.